# How to connect coordinates in Polar plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Currently I'm plotting coordinates in a polar plot using an array of angles with values. I have a text file:

```
[angle] [value]
0 54.3
5 54.4
10 54.2
15 54.4
20 54.6
25 54.4
30 54.2
35 54.4
```

I'm plotting like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define arrays
angles=list()
values=list()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('values.txt')]
for line in lines: # Iterate lines
    stringElement = str.split(line, " ") # Split elements
    angle = int(stringElement[0])
    value = float(stringElement[1])

    angles.append(angle)
    values.append(value)

# Plot values
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

#Plot dots
plt.polar(angles, values, 'k.', zorder=3)

#Plot lines
#plt.polar(angles, values)

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This looks like this:
[image: Cloud of dots]

When I enable the lines, it should connect the dots to the closest neighbor, but connects to other lines instead. This looks like this:

[image]

How to connect the dots to the closest neighbor instead?

Comment: Can it be that your angles in degrees are taken as radians?

Comment: It connects the points in the same order you gave them.

Comment: Indeed, `angles` are expected in radiants. Here it looks like they are given in degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arndt Jonasson pointed out, even though the polar plot displays everything in degrees, it expects the angles in radians. Now it works as it should